# Buying materials or products in CRM

Tags: salesforce, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, zoho

I have a business where I am procuring old Iron scrap, where I have a team of 10 peoples who going to the market daily to buy the scraps. Please bear with me I am new to the CRM or sales activities or sales terms.

Case scenario :1 Team member "Peter"
goes to old market in the city to purchase the scrap iron , when he was going shop by shop to ask for scrap iron. Scrap Iron Person says 300 RS per kg, but Peter says 200 I can give but not 300. So  business didn't happen.

Case scenario :2 Team member "Peter"
goes to old market in the city to purchase the scrap iron , when he was going shop by shop to ask for scrap iron. Scrap Iron Person says 200 RS per kg, so  Peter agreed  200, so business transaction done.

I have purchased a CRM software now.

How can I put into the CRM software these activities so that I can track my team members and their activities. I can see "contacts" "leads" "deals" but not sure which one to choose.

Answer (score 0):

The Zoho-CRM Deals module is probably what you want to look at.  It has a "Pipeline" concept that enables tracking a team-member's activities as they progress through stages.  It is good to read the documentation on Deals because the usage isn't naturally intuitive.  However, once it is understood the Deal module can be helpful.

Here is the current (March 2023) link the the Zoho-CRM Deals module:
https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/crm/sales-force-automation/deal-management/articles/deals-overview